# Acessando variáveis de uma struct

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

Estou estudando C e estou com dúvida na diferença das seguintes linhas:

```
(*depois).agora = 20
```

e

```
*depois.agora = 20;
```

Pelo que entendi o ponto `.` possui prioridade e o compilador iria tentar resolver `depois.agora` e após isso iria resolver `*(depois.agora)`

Então, `depois` é o endereço de memória. se eu tentasse acessar `*(depois.agora)`, eu não estaria pegando o valor que está contido no endereço `depois.agora`?

Qual seria a diferença entre as 2 linhas?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct horario
{
    int hora;
    int minuto;
    int segundo;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct horario agora;
    struct horario *depois;

    depois = &agora; // depois aponta para agora, ou seja, armazena o endereco de memoria de agora

    (*depois).agora = 20; // "atalho": depois->agora = 20

    *depois.agora = 20; // errado, por quê?

    // * = operador de derreferência
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Começo por dizer que está a aceder ao valor incorreto na estrutura em:

```
(*depois).agora = 20; 
*depois.agora = 20;
```

Pois a estrutura `horario` não tem o campo `agora`, por isso teria que trocar para um dos campos da mesma, como por exemplo, `hora`:

```
(*depois).hora = 20; 
*depois.hora = 20;
```

No entanto, o problema tem a ver com precedência de operadores. O operador `.` tem prioridade sobre o operador `*`. Para tornar mais evidente poderíamos reescrever as instruções de acordo com a precedência dos operadores:

```
(*depois).hora = 20; 
*(depois.hora) = 20;
```

Respondendo agora à questão, o `depois` é um ponteiro que aponta para uma estrutura. Por isso tem primeiro que ir ao local de memória onde a estrutura está fazendo `*depois`, e só quando acedeu ao local na memoria andar os *bytes* necessários para chegar ao campo `hora` com `.hora`, o que lhe dá o primeiro caso que especificou:

```
(*depois).hora = 20;
```

Se não colocar os parêntesis, pela precedência dos operadores primeiro é feito `depois.hora` que vai tentar aceder ao ponteiro como se fosse uma estrutura, o que só por si falha logo, porque é um ponteiro e não uma estrutura. O compilador consegue logo perceber pelos tipos que está errado e dá imediatamente um erro de compilação:

> error: request for member 'hora' in something not a structure or
>   union

Lendo atentamente vemos que o compilador indica que estamos a aceder a um campo `hora` de algo que não é uma estrutura ou união (é na verdade um ponteiro). Note também que apenas `depois.hora` é suficiente para gerar o erro.

[Tabela de precedência dos operadores](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: depois[0] irá andar até o local de memória armazenado pelo ponteiro, pois pelo que vi produz o mesmo efeito de usar *depois?

Comment: @Bart O operador de indexação (`[]`) desreferencia o ponteiro, logo permite aceder ao endereço de memória apontado, mas é conceptualmente incorreto para um ponteiro que não aponta para um array.

Answer (score 2):

Essencialmente entendeu tudo.

O primeiro está pegando o valor que está no endereço `depois` e daí pegando o campo `hora` (na pergunta o nome do campo está errado). Os parênteses estão aí justamente para indicar que primeiro vem a derreferência que produzirá um objeto do tipo `struct horario` que por sua vez tem um campo `hora`.

O segundo, por precedência de operadores, está pegando o ponteiro `depois` e tentando acessar o campo `hora` nele, acontece que um ponteiro não tem campos, ele é um endereço e mais nada, então já dá erro. Ele sequer vai tentar usar o operador de derreferência em algo que não faz sentido. É como se fosse:

```
*(depois.agora) = 20;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/Deref.c).

Você só pode acessar um objeto de forma compatível com o conteúdo dele.